# Remove active cursor from form field

Tags: forms, html, input

I have a form that is generated by a plugin on a page. The first input field is focused by default, meaning the cursor is in this field and ready for me to type in my information on page load. I have the form displaying towards the bottom of a page so when I click on any link to the page it jumps down to the location of the form behaving like an anchor link.

Is it possible to remove the focus that is occurring on page load? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
$('#my-form-input').blur();
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page displaying your form?

Comment: It's on my dev system so unfortunately I don't have it live yet but will try to provide a link soon.